# How can I bind two buttons to one function?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 buttons. Let's call someone's name X. On behalf of the other Y. There are three separate buttons in their subclasses.

I wanted to select X first and select the bottom first button of X, another photo, and when I clicked the second bottom button of X, I wanted another photo to come, but I couldn't.

Clicking X has a popup window and other alt buttons appear, but clicking the other Y button scrolls around. It doesn't close again.
When the X and Y upper buttons are clicked on them, buttons should appear below them.Is there anyone who can help?

My code:

```js
function alt1() {
  document.getElementById('myImage').src = '/Users/Hp/Desktop/booo/bo99856/bb0r.png'
}

function alt2() {
  document.getElementById('myImage').src = '/Users/Hp/Desktop/booo/Ff95y/btkt5R.png'
}

function alt3() {
  document.getElementById('myImage').src = '/Users/Hp/Desktop/booo/Ff95y/frknk.png'
}

function alt14() {
  document.getElementById('myImage').src = '/Users/Hp/Desktop/booo/Ff95y/kmanha.png'
}

function alt15() {
  document.getElementById('myImage').src = '/Users/Hp/Desktop/booo/Ff95y/rylean5.png'
}

function alt16() {
  document.getElementById('myImage').src = '/Users/Hp/Desktop/booo/Ff95y/88793cg.png'
}
```

```html
<center>
  <img id="myImage" src='/Users/Hp/Desktop/booo/bo99856/gtR.png' width="750px" height="auto">
  <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('expamle1').style.display='block'"> 
    <img src='/Users/Hp/Desktop/booo/bo99856/btktR.png' width="35px" height="35px"><br><br>Dfl-6127</button>
  <div id="exp">
    <button class="button30" onclick="alt1()"><img src='/Users/Hp/Desktop/booo/bo99856/bb0r.png' width="35px" height="35px"><br></button>
    <button class="button16" onclick="alt2()"><img src='/Users/Hp/Desktop/booo/Ff95y/btkt5R.png' width="35px" height="35px"><br></button>
    <button class="button21" onclick="alt3()"><img src='/Users/Hp/Desktop/booo/Ff95y/frknk.png' width="35px" height="35px"><br></button>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="buton22" onclick="document.getElementById('expamle2').style.display='block'">
        <img src='/Users/Hp/Desktop/booo/bo99856/btktR.png' width="35px" height="35px"><br><br>Dyb-9599</button>
  <div id="expamle2">
    <button class="button19 " onclick="alt14()"><img src='/Users/Hp/Desktop/booo/Ff95y/kmanha.png' width="35px" height="35px"><br><br>KM-HA8</button>
    <button class="button20 " onclick="alt15()"><img src='/Users/Hp/Desktop/booo/Ff95y/rylean5.png' width="35px" height="35px"><br><br>RY-5</button>
    <button class="button21 " onclick="alt16()"><img src='/Users/Hp/Desktop/booo/Ff95y/88793cg.png' width="35px" height="35px"><br><br>88-93</button>
  </div>
</center>
```

Comment: Side note : the `<center>` tag was removed in HTML5 and is [not supported](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp) any longer

Comment: I have read your question 4 or 5 times, slowly, but really I'm having a hard time understanding the problem or what you're trying to achieve. `Clicking X has a popup window and other alt buttons appear`, what popup window? What "other" alt buttons? `clicking the other Y button scrolls around` What "other" Y button? What do you mean "scroll around"? `When the X and Y upper buttons are clicked on them`? Really I'm trying to understand, but the question is extremely confusing

Comment: You could have only _one_ function for all, instead of one function _per button_ : `<button onclick="setImage('image1.png')"><button onclick="setImage('image2.png')">` then `function setImage(url) { myImage.src = url; }`, job done

Comment: I have a slider. There are five buttons of the slider, all of them display different photos.
There are 5 buttons under these five buttons. When you press the first upper button, a car comes, when you press the first of the lower buttons, the color of the car changes. And this is repeated on other buttons. Sorry for my writing.

Comment: This is getting even more confusing ^^ What slider? There is no slider in the code you provided. 5 buttons under 5 buttons? What happened with X and Y? I'm even more confused!

Comment: In summary, I'm trying to make a slider like design your car on the mercedes site.

Answer (score 0):

You can use id property in event to do needful within same function call from different buttons.

```js
function altClick(event) {

  const targetId = event.target.id;

  switch (targetId) {
    case 'btn_0':
      {
        document.getElementById('myImage_0').src = 'https://image.similarpng.com/very-thumbnail/2020/04/Beautiful-Facebook-logo-icon-social-media-png.png';
      }
      break;
    case 'btn_1':
      {
        document.getElementById('myImage_1').src = 'https://sin.ie/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/697029-twitter-512-1.png';
      }
      break;
    case 'btn_2':
      {
        document.getElementById('myImage_2').src = 'https://pngstick.com/imgs//linkedin-png-logo/Linkedin-icon-logo-Transparent-PNG-SVG-vector.png';
      }
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn_0" class="button19" onclick="altClick(event)"><img id="myImage_0" src='/Users/Hp/Desktop/booo/Ff95y/kmanha.png' width="35px" height="35px"><br><br>KM-HA8</button>
<button id="btn_1" class="button20" onclick="altClick(event)"><img id="myImage_1" src='/Users/Hp/Desktop/booo/Ff95y/rylean5.png' width="35px" height="35px"><br><br>RY-5</button>
<button id="btn_2" class="button21" onclick="altClick(event)"><img id="myImage_2" src='/Users/Hp/Desktop/booo/Ff95y/88793cg.png' width="35px" height="35px"><br><br>88-93</button>
```

Comment: As I said in the comments, this (still) enormous amount of code can be reduced to just `function setImage(url) { myImage.src = url; }`.

Comment: I showed you the way, I can reduce it by multiple ways. use event to get parameters from button itself then you will not need switch statement also and hence code will reduce to 3 lines.